# How to return 2 1D arrays from function to main in C

Tags: arrays, c, return, return-type, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *func()
{
   int *a=malloc(5);
   int *b=malloc(5);
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
     a[i]=i+1;
     b[i]=i+5;
   }
   int *l= malloc(2);
   l[0]=a;
   l[1]=b;
   //printf("%p %p ",l[0],l[1]);
   return l;
} 
int main() 
{ 
  int *k=func();
}
```

For the above code, how to return a,b arrays to main function?
Here after assigning values to the two arrays a and b i have given their adresses to new array l. Now after returning l to main, how to peint values of both the arrays a and b in main function?

Comment: The way you use the return value is for sure surprising (an not working if the function [would] returns two arrays).

Comment: You can't. In C you can return (at maximum) **one** value. And that can't be an array. There are various work-arounds but the answer is that it can't be done.

Comment: I don't understand why you make significant change to the question **after** you have accepted an answer - why?

Comment: In general, malloc and free should be done at the same level, preferably in the same function. Create the arrays  in main and pass them to func to be filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in C can only *return* a single thing - that thing can be a `struct` with multiple attributes, but you cannot return and assign multiple independent items like you can in Python or Perl.

If the caller needs several independent items from the function, then you will need to use multiple output parameters - the caller must pass pointers to the things it wants the function to update, and the function updates the things being pointed to:

```
bool f( T *a, T *b )          // for some arbitrary type T
{
  /**
   * The *expressions* *a and *b have type T; writing to *a 
   * and *b in f is equivalent to writing to x and y in main.  
   */
  *a = new_T_value();         // writes a new value to the thing a points to
  *b = another_new_T_value(); // writes a new value to the thing b points to
  return some_boolean_value();
}

int main( void )
{
  T x, y;             // for some arbitrary type T
  if ( f( &x, &y ) )  // f will write new values to x and y
    do_something();
  ...
}
```

We can replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, which gives us:

```
bool f( P **a, P **b )            // for some arbitrary type P
{
  /**
   * The expressions *a and *b have type P *; writing to *a and *b
   * in f is equivalent to writing to x and y in main.
   */
  *a = new_Pstar_value();         // writes a new value to the thing a points to
  *b = another_new_Pstar_value(); // writes a new value to the thing b points to
  return some_boolean_value();
}

int main( void )
{
  P *x, *y;             // for some arbitrary type T
  if ( f( &x, &y ) )    // f will write new values to x and y
    do_something();
  ...
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same - we want the function `f` to write new values to `x` and `y`, so we have to pass pointers to `x` and `y` as arguments.  It's just in this case `x` and `y` already have a pointer type (`P *`), so we wind up passing pointers to pointers (`P **`).

Here’s the most straightforward way that requires the fewest changes to your existing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // need this for malloc

/**
 * We want func to dynamically allocate arrays of int and
 * assign the resulting pointers to *a and *b.  We also want
 * to dynamically allocate and return an array of int *.
 */
int **func( int **a, int **b)
{
   /**
    * malloc(5) allocates 5 *bytes*, not 5 ints.
    * We need to multiply the number of things we 
    * want by the size of each thing.  
    */
   *a=malloc(5 * sizeof **a); // sizeof **a == sizeof (int)
   *b=malloc(5 * sizeof **b);

   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
     /**
      * The postfix [] operator has higher precedence than the
      * unary * operator; we don't want to dereference a[i] and 
      * b[i], we want to index into what a and b *point to*, so
      * we must explicitly group the * operator with the variable
      * name. 
      */
     (*a)[i]=i+1; 
     (*b)[i]=i+5;  
   }
   /**
    * Each l[i] holds a value of type int *,
    * so l needs to have type int **
    */
   int **l= malloc(2 * sizeof *l);
   l[0]=*a;
   l[1]=*b;
   //printf("%p %p ",l[0],l[1]);
   return l;
} 

int main( void ) 
{ 
  int *a, *b;
  int **k=func( &a, &b );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
struct Array
{
    int a[5];
    int b[5];
};

struct Array func( void )
{
    struct Array a = 
    { 
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {1,2,3,4,5}
    };

    return a;
}

int main( void )
{
   struct Array a = func();
   //...
}
```

Another approach is to allocate arrays dynamically and return pointers to the allocated arrays from the function through output parameters. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func( int **a, size_t *n1, int **b, size_t *n2 )
{
    *n1 = 5;
    *a = malloc( sizeof( int ) * *n1 );
    
    if ( *a != NULL )
    {
        int value = 1;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < *n1; i++ )
        {
            ( *a )[i] = value++;
        }
    }
    
    *n2 = 5;
    *b = malloc( sizeof( int ) * *n2 );
    
    if ( *b != NULL )
    {
        int value = 1;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < *n2; i++ )
        {
            ( *b )[i] = value++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int *a = NULL;
    int *b = NULL;
    size_t n1 = 0;
    size_t n2 = 0;
    
    func( &a, &n1, &b, &n2 );
    
    //...

    free( a );
    free( b );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we do without using structures and passing the adresses of 2 arrays ?

Comment: @Anonymous Arrays do not have the assignment operator and you may not return a pointer to a local array with automatic storage duration from a function because it will not be alive after exiting the function.

Comment: Yeah is it possible by declaring arrays dynamically in the function and returning their adresses merged in another array and printing the arrays in main function?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int *func()
{
   int *a=malloc(5);
   int *b=malloc(5);
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
     a[i]=i+1;
     b[i]=i+5;
   }
   int *l= malloc(2);
   l[0]=a;
   l[1]=b;
   //printf("%p %p ",l[0],l[1]);
   return l;
} 
int main() 
{ 
  int *k=func();
}  Like this

Comment: @Anonymous You can allocate array dynamically. See my appended answer.

Comment: But I want using int and not void.

Comment: @Anonymous The return type int of the function does not make a great sense as you want to return two pointers. You can make the return type int with the purpose to report the user of the function whether the dynamic allocation of arrays was successful.

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(int **aa, int **bb)
{
    static int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    static int b[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

    *aa = a;
    *bb = b;
}

void func2(int **aa, int **bb)
{
    int *a = malloc(5 * sizeof(*a)); 
    int *b = malloc(5 * sizeof(*b)); 
    
    memcpy(a, (int []){1,2,3,4,5}, 5 *sizeof(*a));
    memcpy(b, (int []){1,2,3,4,5}, 5 *sizeof(*b));

    *aa = a;
    *bb = b;
}


typedef struct
{
    int a[5];
    int b[5];

}mydata;

mydata func1(void)
{
    mydata d = { .a = {1,2,3,4,5}, .b = {1,2,3,4,5}};
    
    /*  ... */
    return d;
}
```

The second method is very expensive as **the whole struct is being copied** via (in most implementations) stack.

Example usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *a,*b;

    func2(&a, &b);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%zu] = %d, b[%zu]=%d\n", i, a[i], i, b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int *func()
{
   int *a=malloc(5);
   int *b=malloc(5);
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
     a[i]=i+1;
     b[i]=i+5;
   }
   int *l= malloc(2);
   l[0]=a;
   l[1]=b;
   //printf("%p %p ",l[0],l[1]);
   return l;
} 
int main() 
{ 
  int *k=func();
}    Can you simplify this code without using structures?

Comment: `int *a=malloc(5)` ir is wrong!!! You allocate only 5 bytes not 5 integers. See how it has to be done in my answer

Comment: Yeah after initializing I have appended 1 to5 values using for loop to the dynamic array

Comment: you cant "append" values to the array.

Comment: I mean I have assigned values using for loop